# New array for each N element

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of 200~ elements and i'm trying to split that array into smaller arrays by doing it for each N amount of elements, meaning i cannot use the .take / .skip commands, i have currently tried myself with different solutions as:

a Parallel.for and parallel.foreach (Which would be the best if i could figure that out)

and with the normal for and foreach loops, but stuck at the moment, where all i can do is this static solution of creating a new group myself foreach N amount of elements in the arrEtikets

```
string[] arrEtikets = Directory.GetFiles("");

public string[] Group2()
    {
        arrEtikets.Skip(arrEtikets.Length / 10);
        return arrEtikets.Take(arrEtikets.Length / 10).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Do u want an array of arays?

Comment: Why you can't use `Skip` ?

Comment: State your problem clearly. Directory.GetFiles() can be very slow, is that the core of the question? Because everybody is ignoring that. And are you sold on arrays rather than List<> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to split your array to a list of arrays by chunk size using `GroupBy` with no `Skip` or `Take` :

```
private static List<T[]> SplitToChunks<T>(T[] sequence, int chunkSize)
{
    return sequence.Select((item, index) => new { Index = index, Item = item })
                    .GroupBy(item => item.Index / chunkSize)
                    .Select(itemPerPage => itemPerPage.Select(v => v.Item).ToArray())
                    .ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
string[] arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(x=> x.ToString()).ToArray();

var result = SplitToChunks(arr, 101);
```

Comment: but where do i insert my array of data for it to be used, and is it then the SplitToChunks list that holds all my arrays?

Comment: @Pilsneren `result` holds a list of all your arrays. You can loop on `result`

Answer (score 2):

Typical `Skip` + `Take` solution can be something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> SplitArrayWithLinq<T>(T[] source, int size) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  else if (size <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size", "size must be positive");

  return Enumerable
    .Range(0, source.Length / size + (source.Length % size > 0 ? 1 : 0))
    .Select(index => source
      .Skip(size * index)
      .Take(size)
      .ToArray());
}
```

If you are not allowed to use *Linq* (`Skip` as well `Take` included):

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> SplitArray<T>(T[] source, int size) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  else if (size <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size", "size must be positive");

  int n = source.Length / size + (source.Length % size > 0 ? 1 : 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    T[] item = new T[i == n - 1 ? source.Length - size * i : size];

    Array.Copy(source, i * size, item, 0, item.Length);

    yield return item;
  }
}
```

Test (let's split `[1, 2, ... 8, 9]` array into `4` items chunks):

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).ToArray();

var result = SplitArray(source, 4);

string report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  result.Select(item => String.Join(", ", item)));

// 1, 2, 3, 4
// 5, 6, 7, 8
// 9          // <- please, notice that the last chunk has 1 item only
Console.Write(report);
```